# Modified Erdos-Renyi random graph with two different population in python with networkx

Tags: python, networkx, graph-algorithm

I want to implement the following model:

- Take 2*n nodes. The first n nodes represent individuals of type A, and the remaining of type B.
- With probability p, there exists an edge between an individual from A and another from B.

I did it that way, but I want it to be faster:

```
def modified_Erdos_Renyi(n,p):
    G = nx.empty_graph(2*n)
    for i in range (n):       
        for j in range(n,2*n):
            r = rd.random()
            if r<=p:
                G.add_edge(i,j)
    return G
```

I saw that there is a fast algorithm for the traditionnal G_np in networkx sources:

```
def fast_gnp_random_graph(n, p):
    G = empty_graph(n)
    G.name="fast_gnp_random_graph(%s,%s)"%(n,p)

    w = -1
    lp = math.log(1.0 - p)
    v = 1
    while v < n:
        lr = math.log(1.0 - random.random())
        w = w + 1 + int(lr/lp)
        while w >= v and v < n:
            w = w - v
            v = v + 1
        if v < n:
            G.add_edge(v, w)
    return G
```

How could I implement this algorithm with my modified model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm you are trying to create is [already implemented in networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/bipartite/generators.html#random_graph) as `nx.bipartite.random_graph(m,n,p)`.  `m` is the number in group `A`, `n` is the number in group `B`, and `p` is the edge probability.

By the way - if you want to understand why `fast_gnp_random_graph` works, I recommend section 2 of [this paper I cowrote with one of the original developers of networkx](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f375/3dfc4171cdb3541cef127417176dd7b08002.pdf).